# general question about reactJS, nodeJS and NPM

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

first, the "facts" that I know:

1. reactJS is frontend framework, after compiling it'll generate a bundle of html/js/css files that can be recognized by modern browsers, so the browser straightforward request the web host server for these static html files ;
2. nodeJS is a server-side environment, or sometimes people call it a backend framework, browsers don't understand nodeJS but have to request the web host server to interpret it and to send back the html response.
3. according to wiki, npm is a package manager for the JavaScript programming language. It is the default package manager for the JavaScript runtime environment Node.js.

my question is:

1. is my understanding correct
2. why reactJS also using npm and includes node_module, does it have something to do with nodeJS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript is the programming language used in both Node.js and in the browser, but that's about as far as the similarities goes. Node uses the V8 engine, which is the same running in the chrome browser.

Even though they use the same engine, they are quite different. They both have plenty of APIs - most notably, the browser has the DOM (which allows you to render stuff to the screen). In Node.js you do not have the DOM, but there are other APIs, for accessing the filesystem for instance.

Since both are running JavaScript, you can try to run the same program both in node and in the browser, but it will sometimes fail. React is a front-end framework which uses the DOM, so if you try to run React in node, it will crash because in Node there is no DOM (Node has no screen to render to). If you try to run a program suited for Node.js in the browser, it will crash if it uses some Node-specific API.

The confusing bit is that npm is a package manager for JavaScript, not necessarily node (even though node is in the name..). Therefore, we can use npm also for web applications. (If we do, we need to use a bundler like webpack though).

Some npm modules might work both in the browser and in node, but some will only work on one of them. If the npm module requires some platform-spcific API (DOM for the browser for example) then it will not work for the other platform.

Hope that clears things out! I understand that it's a bit of a mess..

Comment: Cool, your explanation really cleared up my doubts, thanks